# Can two threads never act on the same object at the same time

Tags: java, concurrency

I would like to know.

Can two threads never act on the same object at the same time or can they

Also

Does Each thread runs in its own JVM in java.

Comment: This is an OK question - but to get better answers you should explain what you have read/tried so far

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is nothing to stop two threads working on the same object. Synchronization is the mechanism where you can specify, in the code, that access from different threads should be controlled - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Each thread runs within the same JVM (assuming you are not running in some fancy, clustered environment. If you don't know what this means, then you're not :-))

Answer (score 0):

Read the java documentation for threads.

If only read-operations are made on objects, than there can be something you may call "acting on the same object the same time".